# Sandbox Solution filling up Resource Quota (SharePoint 2013)

Tags: development, event-receivers

So, I created a very simple Event Receiver that triggers on the `ItemUpdating` Event for Document Libraries. All it does is get the original file modified date and changes the SharePoint file modified date to the original one.

When I add the solution to the gallery and activate it and it's feature it seems to run fine using very few resources and doing what I want. However, after about an hour, all of a sudden, it starts filling up the resource quota very fast (even when no one is using the site collection).

This could very definitely be something wrong with my code, but I don't see anything that should be eating up resource points that fast:

```
  public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
        using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
        {
            properties.ListItem["Modified"] = properties.ListItem.File.Properties["vti_ct"];

            properties.ListItem.Update();
            web.Update();
        }
    }
```

I tried it without the `using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb()){...}` and it still did the same thing. This has been super annoying as it will continually reach over 1000 resource points and shutdown all other solutions as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating inside the event receiver that fires another event. So to avoid that disable Event Firing as below

```
this.EventFiringEnabled = false;
using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
{
   properties.ListItem["Modified"] = properties.ListItem.File.Properties["vti_ct"];

   properties.ListItem.Update();
   web.Update();
}
this.EventFiringEnabled = true;
```